# Spike Slab in r, bad output

Tags: r

I've successfully used Spike Slab in the past, but with this data it seems like something is going wrong. My code is:

```
>require(spikeslab)
>set.seed(2)
>model1_ss<-with(data_use,spikeslab(gdeaths_per_100_thousand~gdealers_per_100_thousand+Physically.Unhealthy.Days+Mentally.Unhealthy.Days, na.rm=TRUE))
>summary(model1_ss)
```

the first 10 lines of data_use is

```
 Physically.Unhealthy.Days  Mentally.Unhealthy.Days gdeaths_per_100_thousand    gdealers_per_100_thousand
 5.2        4.1     19.70210418  30.11828855
 4.9        4.1     21.6723146   32.83851989
 5.1        4.3     23.52217417  39.4076506
 5.1        3.6     NA           38.03625359
 3.4        4.1     17.78983533  27.28191219
 3.4        4.2     19.4576324   32.2906761
 3.3        3.8     13.9248167   40.75855495
 3.3        3.8     12.05513916  36.2194827
 5.9        3.9     NA           31.52340694
```

And it returns this, which is totally unlike what I expect from from Spike Slab:

```
    Length Class      Mode     
summary           4  data.frame list     
verbose          10  -none-     list     
terms             3  terms      call     
sigma.hat         1  -none-     numeric  
y              2132  -none-     numeric  
xnew          12792  -none-     numeric  
x             12792  -none-     numeric  
y.center          1  -none-     numeric  
x.center          6  -none-     numeric  
x.scale           6  -none-     numeric  
names             6  -none-     character
bma               6  -none-     numeric  
bma.scale         6  -none-     numeric  
gnet              6  -none-     numeric  
gnet.scale        6  -none-     numeric  
gnet.path         2  -none-     list     
gnet.obj         16  lars       list     
gnet.obj.vars     6  -none-     numeric  
gnet.parms        6  -none-     numeric  
phat              1  -none-     numeric  
complexity      500  -none-     numeric  
ridge           500  -none-     list     
model           500  -none-     list
```

Is there a way to interpret this that I don't know about? Or is there something wrong with how I'm running it? Thanks so much for any help, I have no idea what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no `summary` method for objects of class `spikeslab`, so the default summary method is used which prints the internal list elements.

Just print the object to get a nice summary - maybe that's what you want? Is this the output you expected?

```
> model1_ss
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Variable selection method     : AIC 
Big p small n                 : FALSE 
Screen variables              : FALSE 
Fast processing               : TRUE 
Sample size                   : 7 
No. predictors                : 3 
No. burn-in values            : 500 
No. sampled values            : 500 
Estimated mse                 : 7.5765 
Model size                    : 2 


---> Top variables:
                            bma  gnet bma.scale gnet.scale
Mentally.Unhealthy.Days   2.290 2.331    13.003     13.236
Physically.Unhealthy.Days 0.926 0.951     1.084      1.113
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```